# Spring-boot with JPA Repositories using JTA Transaction Manager using JBOSS 6

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss, spring-boot, jta

Currently i am working on a spring-boot application, which is using the JPA Repositories and HornetQ JMS. I want spring boot to use the JTA Transaction manager to manager the distributed transactions as default "transactionManager". We are currently using the @Annotation based configuration for spring. We have also enable @EnabledSpringAutoConfiguration for spring boot. Can you please help me with the configuration that will allow me to use Spring-Boot with the JTA Transaction Manger. Any help or pointer are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I created few JTA examples with Spring Boot](https://github.com/lkrnac/book-eiws-code-samples/tree/master/07-jta). I didn't use JBoss, but they may help anyway as they use JDBC data store and JMS broker.

**Some of the examples are failing intentionally**, because they were created as examples for the book.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply !! jut a quick question, In this (https://github.com/lkrnac/book-eiws-code-samples/blob/master/07-jta/0702-jta-java-config/src/main/java/net/lkrnac/book/eiws/chapter07/JtaConfiguration.java) Jta Config you have overridden the default "transactionManager" to use atomikos, if you dont specify any wont spring-boot create a default JtaTransactionManager based on the environment,  if you deploy it on JBoss ?? The reason for this is i havnt specified any transactionManager and trying to deploy it on JBoss, but its still not creating me the JtaTransactionManager :(

Comment: Sorry not sure how to obrain/create JtaTransactionManager from JBoss. AFAIK it should be provided by JEE container. So I bet some JNDI call will be needed.

Comment: @sagar27 i have a similar kind of problem, only the thing is that I dont need to use the JtaTransactionManager created by JBOSS but I want to use the defaulttransactionManager created by Spring boot. But everytime I start jboss, the JtaTransactionManager picks up. Can you help ?

Comment: user641887 - Currently what we are doing is just creating a primary bean with the JPATransaction Manage and passing that to @EnableJpaRepositories boot annotation (transactionManagerRef=<new JPA transaction manage>). Let me know if you need more details on this.